# "Restrict" versus "constrict"

Tags: verbs

What's the difference? The dictionary definitions sound awfully similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Restrict* means to limit or control a thing; *constrict* means to tighten or narrow something, usually by applying pressure. Here's a sentence that illustrates the difference:

> The snake coiled around his torso, constricting his chest; this, in turn, restricted his breathing.

Comment: Right. My confusion arises from the fact that narrowing/tightening something (i.e. constricting it) is one way to limit (i.e. restrict) that thing. In other words, constricting something implies the restriction of another thing.

Comment: @Jasper Loy: Agreed. I myself would use *constrain* as a synonym for *restrict* before I would turn to *constrict* for that purpose.